# Google GeoCoding Query

Tags: java, google-maps

I am doing "Address Validation". My Address table has "Street Address", "City", "State", "Postal Code", "Country". I am using Google MAP API to validate my address.

I gave my address like

1. Street Address -- "kajhfkjdhfkjdsh"
2. City -- ksjfdlsjflsdjflk
3. State -- AP
4. PostalCode -- 500087
5. Country -- India

In this example only State, PostalCode, Country are valid and the remaining fields are invalid. But when I use the Google Map's API its saying its a valid address. But the street address and city are invalid.
So as per my observation the address validation is done only based on 3 fields those are (State, Postal Code, Country). So How can I validate Street and city along with the remaining fields with GOOGLE MAPS API?

Or is there any way/other (API) to validate all the fields in my address table.

Can anyone help me on this. I am stuck over here.

Comment: Are you using the geocoding API? Also, is it the Javascript or the webservice?

Comment: I am using GeoCode API. I am using the Webservice through Java. How I need to validate the street address and city...?

Comment: The geocoder is not an address validator.  It can be used for that purpose, but its purpose is to convert addresses to coordinates.  It makes a best guess given the information provided.

Answer (score 0):

When trying this address with the google geocoding service http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?sensor=false&address=kajhfkjdhfkjdsh,ksjfdlsjflsdjflk,AP,500087,India I see the result is of type `postal_code` and partial_match is set to true.

Trying real address I get the result type as `street_address` and the `partial_match` flag is missing.

I suggest you make some tests and check the content of the service result. This is a geocoding service, so it aims to give you a location to point your map to, not to validate addresses.

Comment: Hi David, Thanq for your reply. You are right if its not a valid address it will show "partial_match" and if it is a valid address it's not showing. But Here I gave a valid example like "Ramatakis lane,AP,522426,India". Its my home address but its giving "Partial_match" flag. So how can I do based on these flags...?